# loop through gtsummary table to pick out only significant variables

Tags: r, loops, logistic-regression, gtsummary

I have a question.  I am, relatively new to R. I am transitioning some code from another app to R.  In that code, I was able to loop through a table and pick out only the significant variables based on the p-value and the size of the odds ratio for logistic regression.  Then I was able to say something like "x had a significant link with y" when the p was less than or equal to 0.05 and the odds ratio as above 1.00 and do the converse "x had a significant negative link with " when the p value was less than 0.05 and the odds ration was below 1.00.  Then, I was able to do what I understand from the gtsummary literature is inline_text these statements.  As I am trying to get my bearings with R, I was wondering how I would I accomplish this with gtsummary tables?  My reproducible code does not work, but it is below:

```
# install.packages("gtsummary")
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

#simulated data
gender <- sample(c(0,1), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
age <- round(runif(1000, 18, 80))
xb <- -9 + 3.5*gender + 0.2*age
p <- 1/(1 + exp(-xb))
y <- rbinom(n = 1000, size = 1, prob = p)
mod <- glm(y ~ gender + age, family = "binomial")
summary(mod)

#create the gtsummary table
tab1 = mod %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gt::tab_source_note(gt::md("*This data is simulated*")) 

#attempt of going through the gtsummary table
for (i in 1:nrow(tab1[1:3,])) {  # does one row at a time
  pv = tab1[["_data"]]$p.value
  num = tab1[i, "pv"]
  name = tab1[i, "variable"]
  if(pv <=0.05 ){
    cat("The link between", name, "and is significant. ")
  }
}
```

I ask about the gtsummary regression table because, I will have to do the same thing with the tbl_summary as well.  I thought I would begin with the regression version.  The idea is to get the gorgeous inline_text via an if else.  All of this is triggered by the going down the p-value column, and then pulling the name of the variable and the amazing inline_text information into the sentence.  I have looked through the available questions others have asked, but I haven't found anything that gets to the heart of this.  If I have missed it, please, point me in the correct direction.

Comment: Check out the `filter_p()` function from the gtsummary pkg. Does that do what you need?

Comment: I did and I ran the examples from the website.  This is not what I am trying to do.  My focus is on the inline_text.  My data above has two variables that are statistically significant.  I am trying to get a loop to go through each of the rows of the gtsummary table in the p.value column.  For each of these variables, using a if or ifelse statement, decide whether to write the significance statements.  I could coerce the gtsummary table to a data frame and do this, but then I think I couldn't use the inline_text features to pull the correct information into the sentence.  How do I fix this?

Comment: I am updating my loop from above: ` tab1 = as.data.frame(tab1)   for (i in 1:nrow(tab1[1:2,])) { 
  pv =tab1[i,"p.value"]
  name = tab1[i, "variable"]
  if(pv <=0.05 ){
    cat("The link between", name, "and is significant. ")
  }
} `  Now, I am trying to figure out how to use inline_text in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a data frame in every gtsummary table called `x$table_body`. I think it's easier to extract the information you need from there. Example below! (you could also wrap the last line in an `inline_text()` if that is better for you).

```r
# install.packages("gtsummary")
library(gtsummary)
#> #BlackLivesMatter
library(tidyverse)

#simulated data
gender <- sample(c(0,1), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
age <- round(runif(1000, 18, 80))
xb <- -9 + 3.5*gender + 0.2*age
p <- 1/(1 + exp(-xb))
y <- rbinom(n = 1000, size = 1, prob = p)
mod <- glm(y ~ gender + age, family = "binomial")

#create the gtsummary table
tab1 = mod %>% tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) 

# extract the variable names and the pvalues
tab1$table_body %>%
  select(variable, p.value) %>%
  filter(p.value <= 0.05) %>% # only keep the sig pvalues
  deframe() %>%
  imap(~str_glue("The link between 'y' and {.y} is significant ({style_pvalue(.x, prepend_p = TRUE)})."))
#> $gender
#> The link between 'y' and gender is significant (p<0.001).
#> 
#> $age
#> The link between 'y' and age is significant (p<0.001).
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Sorry I had to teach class.  When you say wrap the last line in a inline_text are you meaning, replace this with an inline_text setup?  How would that work to keep the flexibility with the different covariates (e.g., age and gender) while matching their correct inline_text information?  I ask because the inline_text would be amazing for my work.

Comment: I mean to do something like this: `imap(~inline_text(variable = .y, pattern = "{p.value}"))`

Comment: I see.  With the pattern, I could expand this to provide more information (e.g., odds ratio and CI), correct?  Tomorrow, with fresh eyes, I will try this and report back.  Thank you

Comment: Good Morning, would this be how the inline_text should be written:   #imap(~str_glue("The link between 'y' and {.y} is significant `r inline_text(variable = .y, pattern = "{p.value}")`))?  At the moment, this does not work.  This is the error that I am getting:  Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): unexpected '{'     imap(~str_glue("The link between 'y' and {.y} is significant `r inline_text(variable = .y, pattern = "{.  The issue is with the { in the pattern argument.  In markdown I am putting this in the code chunk, should it be outside of the code chunk to render to a word document?

Comment: You can't mix `r code_goes_here()` syntax within the `map()`

Comment: I am still getting errors.  This is coming down to my lack of knowledge of tidyverse to be able to integrate the inline_text version properly.  I will mark the first answer as satisfying the question because it does.  Thank you for trying.